# Javascript "document.getElementById" wildcard loop?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vb.net, loops

Can wildcards be used with the Javascript "document.getElementById" line?

I have a Vb.net form with 3 div elements ("page1, page2, page3"). What I'm hoping to accomplish is allowing the user to click a button or hyperlink button that will navigate them to the next div ("page#"). Is there a way to do something like the following & loop through each element that has an ID like "page1", "page2", "page3", etc without hard coding?

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
var e = document.getElementById(id);
if(e.style.display == 'none')
e.style.display = 'block';
else
e.style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: That's one of the advantage of jQuery

Answer (score 1):

For what I understand, you are looking for the querySelectorAll function and a for-in loop:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='page']");
for(var e in elements){
   // do Stuff - each element get's reached by elements[e]
}
```

for example:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='page']");
for(var e in elements){
   if(elements[e].style.display == 'none')
        elements[e].style.display = 'block';
    else
        elements[e].style.display = 'none';
}
```

this will catch all elements with an id starting with the word "page" and toggle their visibility

Comment: @SimplyCraig no please look at https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: Much better to use a plain *for* loop rather than *for..in*, particularly as the [*HTMLCollection*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110705/common-dom-interfaces.html#htmlcollection-0) returned by *querySelectorAll* has enumerable properties that aren't elements. Also better to set the *display* property to `""` (empty string) when showing elements so that they adopt their default or inherited style.

Comment: @RobG I just reused his function for an example, because I don't know what he really wants to do with the elements, but you are right.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Short answer: no, this is not possible.</strike> As Markai has pointed out, it is possible. I still feel like using a class is more appropriate, as this better captures the semantics.

A bit longer answer: perhaps you can give each element a `class="page"`. Then you can hide all elements with that class and only display the one you're interested in. You can get elements with class 'page' by using `document.getElementsByClassName('page')` or the more friendly jQuery selector `$('.page')`.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop the elements. Instead of a toggle, hide all elements except the one you want.

```
function EnableVisibility(elementName, elementId)
{
    for(i=1;i<4;i++)
    {
        if(i == elementId)
             document.getElementById(elementName + i).style.display = 'block';
        else
             document.getElementById(elementName + i).style.display = 'none';
    }
}

EnableVisibility("page", 2); // This would hide all pages and display page2
```

If you don't like the hardcoded 4, you could change the for loop with a while and if getElementById returns a null then exit the loop.

I personally like the class idea from Martijn and instead of changing the style directly you add or remove a class ex: class="page visible" class="page hidden"